# Is there a proper substitute for the .count() method in my code?

Tags: python, function

Currently I'm writing a code that finds duplicates within entered strings and indicates how many letters there are that have duplicates, e.g "aaaaaaabbbcccddddeeeeee" would output 5. While the overall code appears to work well enough the issue comes in regards to how the .count() function works.

```
x = 0
def increment():
    global x
    x = x +1
def duplicate_count(text):
    for i in text:
        number = text.count(i)
        if number == 1:
            pass
        elif number != 1:
            increment()
        else:
            pass
        new_text = text.replace(i, "")
        return duplicate_count(new_text)
    return x
print(duplicate_count('abcdeaB'))
```

The resulting outputs here return 1 instead of 2 because of the fact that 'b' and 'B' are not considered to be the same, this in turn is screwing up the results as the [answers on the codewars website](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54bf1c2cd5b56cc47f0007a1/train/python) for which this question exists, wants it to consider 'b' and 'B' to be the same character. How would I replace this as a function or change the functionality of the code here?

Comment: just lowercase your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Set` returns unique values. So first convert the `text` into `set`, this will give us unique letters.
- Create `list` of unique letters.
- loop thrugh list using `for loop`.
- using [str.count](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) count the occurrance of each letter.
- Use `if-else` statement to check the occurrance of each letter. if it is greater then 1 print the letter and its count.

```
  def duplicate_count(text):
    "" " set returns unique value. So first create a list of all unique value."""
    unique_letters = list(set(text))
    print(f'\n{text}')
    for i in unique_letters:
        if text.count(i) > 1 :
            count = text.count(i)
            print(f"{i} occured {count} times.")



duplicate_count('abcde')
duplicate_count('aabbcde')
duplicate_count('aabBcde')
duplicate_count('indivisibility')
duplicate_count('Indivisibilities')
duplicate_count('aA11')
duplicate_count('ABBA')

# 
# abcde
# 
# aabbcde
# a occured 2 times.
# b occured 2 times.
# 
# aabBcde
# a occured 2 times.
# 
# indivisibility
# i occured 6 times.
# 
# Indivisibilities
# i occured 6 times.
# s occured 2 times.
# 
# aA11
# 1 occured 2 times.
# 
# ABBA
# B occured 2 times.
# A occured 2 times.
```

Comment: Wow this is incredibly in-depth, will look into this code further for future reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your input string to lower case, like this:

```py
def duplicate_count(text):
    text = text.lower()
    for i in text:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set to count unique letters like this one. Set can have only uniue values. Loop over set and if letter count greater than 2 we add 1 to list. Finally we make sum over list.

```
def duplicate_count(text: str):
    text = text.lower()
    return sum([1 for t in set(text) if text.count(t) - 1])
```

Comment: Yep that's an interesting take on the problem, noted for future purposes, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dictionary  , a.lower() to make all letters lower case

```
a="aaAAgaaabBbcccddDdeeeeee"
def duplicate_count(text):
    dict1={}
    for letter in a.lower():
        dict1[letter]=dict1.get(letter,0)+1
    dict1 = dict((k, v) for k, v in dict1.items() if v > 1)
    return len(dict1)
print(duplicate_count(a))
```

for every letter in sentence adds it as key in dictionary with value its frequency
if key is empty it returns 0
finally we reconstruct the dictionary with frequencies(values) >1 for duplicates

Comment: This is an interesting solution, although I just switched the string to lowercase and then did the count function. I'll be sure to keep this in mind however!

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.Counter` to do the counting; then you can filter out the unique items to get your answer.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sum(1 for _, count in Counter("aaaaaaabbbcccddddeeeeee").items if count > 1)
5
```

Comment: This is an interesting import library, will look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by converting the string to all lowercase characters, but you only need to do that once when the function is first called:

```
x = 0

def increment():
    global x
    x += 1

def duplicate_count(text, lowered=False):
    if not lowered:
        text = text.lower()
    for i in text:
        number = text.count(i)
        if number != 1:
            increment()
        new_text = text.replace(i, "")
        return duplicate_count(new_text, True)

    return x

print(duplicate_count('abcdeaB'))  # -> 2
```

Comment: I'd assume it would be inefficient to continuously call the function and lower it each time?

Comment: @Sh4dy: It only converts them once when it's first called, and besides, if you're so concerned about efficiency, why are you doing this recursively? IMO, that's a very poor way to do things plus this implementation involves using a global variable, another poor practice — I was merely showing you how to make what you had *work*.